# Different namespace for same prefix for multiple XMLs with MOXy

Tags: xml, namespaces, jaxb, moxy

I have some troubles with setting up different namespace URI for the same prefix in multiple different XML files while unmarshaling, the structure of XML is as follows:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<pdi:company xmlns:rdp="rdp_namespace_uri" xmlns:pdi="pdi_namespace_uri" name="test">
  <division rdp:id="id_1" rdp:type="org" name="Financial">data</division>
  <division rdp:id="id_2" rdp:type="org"  name="Personal">data</division>  
</pdi:company>
```

Each file structure is the same, only the RDP namespace and PDI namespace is for each XML file different. Since namespace is defined as static final variable, I am not able to change it once it's been set. My Java class looks like this:

```java
@XmlRootElement(name = "company", namespace = JAXBProperties.pdiNamespace)
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Company {

    private ArrayList<Division> divisions;
}
```

and JAXBProperties class:

```java
public class JAXBProperties {

    public static final String rdpNamespace = "rdp_namespace_uri";
    public static final String pdiNamespace = "pdi_namespace_uri";
}
```

I need to dynamically change rdpNamespace and pdiNamespace variables for each file. How can I accomplish this?

I cannot change the structure of XML itself, e.g. simply rewrite the namespace URI, since these XML files are from different sources and only thing I am supposed to do is unmarshal them into object representation.

Let's have an example, this would be defined for company_1.xml with PDI namespace strictly given, as follows:

```java
@XmlRootElement(name = "company", namespace = "http://www.example.com/PDI_1")
public class Company {
```

For another file company_2.xml, the namespace is different (I have to manually rewrite it):

```java
@XmlRootElement(name = "company", namespace = "http://www.example.com/PDI_2")
public class Company {
```

Whenever I try to unmarshal file without changing the namespace in @XmlRootElement to corresponding namespace within its file's xmlns:pdi tag, I get an error, let's say I try to unmarshal file company_2.xml with PD_1 namespace:

```
Exception Description: A descriptor with default root element {http://www.example.com/PDI_2}company was not found in the project]
```

When I manually change the namespace in @XmlRootElement to PD_2, everything works fine. I would like to dynamically update namespace in @XmlRootElement, but when I try to set it dynamically (via dynamically created variable) I get an error:

```
The value for annotation attribute XmlRootElement.namespace must be a constant expression
```

I hope my question is clear enough, I am struggling to get this work.
Or is there any other solution to bypass the namespace checking ?(I prefer not to turn off namespace awareness)

Comment: Any solution requiring control over namespace prefixes will be misguided as it is the namespace URIs, not the namespace prefixes, that become parts of namespaced component names.  Have you lead with your Y when you should be asking about your X?  (See [What is the XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?)

Comment: @kjhughes The problem is that I am not able or more specifically cannot change the URIs directly in these XML files, they come from different sources and are automatically generated by different programs, only the structure is the same, I've posted only the example of what these files look like

Comment: Sorry, it's still not clear to me what your end goal is, but perhaps you'll find Blaise Doughan's [JAXB and Namespace Prefixes](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/11/jaxb-and-namespace-prefixes.html) post helpful.  Good luck.

Comment: @kjhughes thanks, I've read it already along with many other articles with no answer to my particular problem, actually I've edited my question to give better explanation of my problem, thank you for help